# How to stop a (Perl) script on Unix exiting when it encounters errors?

Tags: linux, perl, error-handling

I have a Perl script inherited from a colleague which processes some data for me. On our old server it will run and return several expected error messages before generating an output file for me. It works fine for what I need. However I recently moved it from our old server to a new, larger group server, without making any other edits – and now it appears to be exiting after the first error rather than continuing to run. No further errors appear and no output file is generated.

**How can I make this script run all the way through despite the errors? I would like to try and address this at the server/Unix level rather than the Perl code itself, because the script works fine on our other server already.**

Additional details:

On our old server I was using Perl 5.26.1 – on the new server that’s not installed but I get the same error with Perl 5.16, 5.22.1 and 5.28.0 so I don't think it's a Perl version issue.

I have tried using “set +e” and this didn’t help.

The exit status is coming back as 255 ie exit status out of range. I don't know what exit status it gave on the old server as I don't currently have access to it.

The new server uses univa grid engine to queue jobs, but I tried running the script on the login nodes and get the same issue so I don’t think it is a UGE-specific issue.

Comment: `set +e` is something that changes how a shell script functions, it will likely not work in a Perl script.  This question is more suited for https://stackoverflow.com/ as it is a Perl programming question. I can't however migrate the question over there as it does not fulfill their criteria for how to ask ([no source code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), so no way to investigate what's wrong). I suggest that you delete the question here and re-ask it over at SO.

Comment: Thanks, because the script worked fine on my previous server (and hasn't been edited) I would really like to try and solve it at that level rather than diving into the Perl script itself - but if I get stuck I will try this and add source code.

Comment: So, please show the script. There are many possibilities, but if we could look at the script, or at least a minimal variant of it that still exhibit the same behavior,  we would not only be able to tell you what's happening, but also how to fix it, without having to resort to generic answers, guesses, or debugging tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug perl script line by line by using :

```
perl -d script.pl
```

It will prompt you like below

```
DB<1>
```

just keep typing 'n' until the end of script reached.You can see where script throws error and troubleshoot the script based on that.

Comment: Thanks! I would really like to solve it at the level of the server/Unix, because the identical script works fine on my other server, but if I need to debug in Perl this will be v useful.